# jQuery tablesorter not initializing when tested with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine, tablesorter

I'm having issues testing a jQuery tablesorter table (with server-side sorting) with Jasmine.  The table never seems to make any AJAX calls.  In the code below, it will fail at `expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toContain(reportsListUrl);`. "reportsListUrl" is the base of my `tablesorterPager.ajaxUrl`.

It seems as though tablesorter is failing to make any sort of 
AJAX calls during Jasmine testing.  The table functions perfectly in practice with no errors.

Here is my Jasmine test:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "fixtures";

describe("Admin Manage Reports", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        loadFixtures("admin_manage_reports_template.html");
        jasmine.Ajax.install();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
    });

    it("calls reportsListUrl when pagerUpdate triggered", function() {
        expect(adminWriteAccess).toBeDefined();
        expect(reportsListUrl).toBeDefined();
        expect(deleteUrl).toBeDefined();
        expect(usersUrl).toBeDefined();
        expect(json).toBeDefined();
        expect(table).toBeDefined();
        expect(window.setUpReportsTable).toBeDefined();
        expect(window.updateReportsTable).toBeDefined();
        expect(window.clearFilters).toBeDefined();
        // jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(/.*/).andReturn({
        //     "responseText": "foo"
        // });
        spyOn(window, "updateReportsTable");
        window.updateReportsTable();
        expect(window.updateReportsTable).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toContain(reportsListUrl);
    });
});
```

Please forgive my javascript if it's not the best.  I'm not a js developer by trade, and Jasmine is new to me.  Any ideas why tablesorter may be failing to make any AJAX requests? `jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent()` is undefined...

`TypeError: jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent(...) is undefined in file:///xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/tests/ui/test-admin-manage-reports.js (line 30)`

Comment: What makes you think tablesorter is the problem? I don't see tablesorter called anywhere in your code.

Comment: @jordaniac89 Sorry, I was unsure of exactly how much context to give.  I guess too much would be better than too little.  `updateReportsTable` is just a wrapper for the following: `$(".download-table").trigger('pagerUpdate', 1);`. I can post all of my tablesorter code as well, but I figured the post would get pretty extensive pretty quickly.  I figured it was enough to indicate that tablesorter is working just fine... just not in conjunction with Jasmine (seemingly).

Comment: I don't know jasmine very well, but if you want to grab the url before the ajax call goes out, you can add code in the [`customAjaxUrl` callback](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-customajaxurl), or to the [`ajaxProcessing` callback](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing) immediately after a successful ajax.